# Get <td> value string given the jQuery <tr> object

Tags: jquery, json, html

I have an HTML table that has N rows and 7 columns.
[image]

I used a jQuery select to find all the rows of the table.

```
$("#TaskListing table tr").each(function (index, element) { codeBlock })
```

I want to grab the values for columns **Id, Category and Title** and save all this to a .json file on the server that is hosting the html page.

What code would I use in the codeBlock to get at the Id, Category and Title values per row?

Below is the code I use to populate the table.

```
var tableObj = $("#TaskListing table").append(
    "<tr class=rows id=TaskId>" +
      "<td id=Begin><input id=onoff type=checkbox " + ischecked + "></td>" +
      "<td id=Unique>" + idnum + "</td>" +
      "<td id=Cat contenteditable='true'>" + catstr + "</td>" +
      "<td id=Title contenteditable='true'>" + titlestr + "</td>" +
      "<td id=Time ondblclick=\"editElapsedTime(" + idnum + ")\">" + timeStr + "</td>" +
      "<td id=Percent>0</td>" +
      "<td id=Trash><input name=TrashInput" + idnum + " type=image src=trashcan.jpg height=30 width=30 /></td>" +
    "</tr>"
);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using https://datatables.net/ if you want to save time in the long run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store all the elements of `td` for each rows, and get the respective `td` using `.eq()` like so :

```
var dataStore = [];

$("#TaskListing table tr").each(function (index, element) { 

    // store each td for each iterated rows
    var tds = $( this ).find( 'td' );
    // .eq(1) is a zero-based, then start with 1 for column no 2
    var idClmn = tds.eq(1); // id column
    var catClmn = tds.eq(2);  // category column
    var titClmn = tds.eq(3);  // title column
    var obj = {};

    // getting text
    console.log( idClmn.text(), catClmn.text(), titClmn.text() );

    // here continue populate data into object or else
    obj.id = idClmn.text();
    obj.category = catClmn.text();
    obj.title = titClmn.text();
    // push onto 
    dataStore.push( obj );

});

console.log( dataStore );
```

*P/s : `id=TaskId`, id's must be unique. You can replace it with class instead. Same goes to id's of td*

Answer (score 2):

this will create a json object.

```
var jsonObj = [];
$("#TaskListing table tr").each(function (index, element) { 

item = {}
item ["id"] = $(this).find('td#Unique').text();
item ["Cat"] = $(this).find('td#Cat').text();
item ["Title"] = $(this).find('td#Title').text();

jsonObj.push(item);
});
```